# How can I make relative movement in GameMaker studio?

Tags: game-maker

I know I can change the `hspeed` and `vspeed` properties on my object. Assume I do it for the directional diamond in a squared-style movement game (not necesarily snapping to tiles, but it could). So the following scenarios apply (for any constant K) for my `obj_Hero` object:

- Pressing UP: vspeed is -K, hspeed is 0
- Pressing DOWN: vspeed is K, hspeed is 0
- Pressing LEFT: vspeed is 0, hspeed is -K
- Pressing RIGHT: vspeed is 0, hspeed is +K
- Otherwis: vspeed and hspeed are 0
- Only one directional arrow at the same time will be considered (the last pressed).

My player starts from position of an `obj_Start` object, and wins when reaching (colliding) an `obj_End` object. In the meantime, an `obj_Enemy` will be chasing the player using a *step avoid* strategy to avoid the player. The player loses if the enemy collides with him. Assuming I can correctly select the enemy current direction sprite, I'm done.

So far, so good.

Now assume some parts of my game have moving platforms. They have a specific platform speed vector (PSH, PSV), assuming I have such constants.

I know I could always condition my player movement speed to be:

- `(K + PSH, PSV)` for player moving right
- `(-K + PSH, PSV)` for player moving left
- `(PSH, K + PSV)` for player moving down
- `(PSH, -K + PSV)` for player moving up
- `(PSH, PSV)` for player not moving

But... How do I alter (relative to the platform movement, as I do with the player) the enemy movement when it is actually generated by the *step avoiding* strategy?

Answer (score 0):

When an enemy is standing on the platform add dx and dy to the enemy's position each frame where dx and dy are the change in the platforms position. Do it manually through gml in addition to the step avoid code. It should work just fine.